# Verificar si un programa está o no instalado sin cerrarse antes de finalizar la ejecución

Tags: batch, .bat

Tengo este programa que pretende evaluar si un programa (en este caso DOSBox) está instalado en el sistema. En el caso de que el usuario responda que sí (desea descargado) a modo de prueba, y muestre un mensaje echo Felicidades, ¡entró al segundo if! de lo contrario aparezca otro mensaje que diga echo No se puede ejecutar programas DOS en sistemas de 64 bits.

El programa se cierra inmediatamente después que lo abro.

Lo estoy ejecutando desde un archivo bat

```
@echo off
chcp 65001 > NUL
echo Verificación sencilla iniciada.

    where dosbox >nul 2>&1
    if %errorlevel% equ 0 (
        echo DOSBox está instalado en el sistema.
    ) else (
        set /p respuesta=DOSBox no está instalado. ¿Desea descargarlo? (s/n): 
        if /I "%respuesta%"=="s" (
            echo Felicidades, ¡entró al segundo if!
        ) else (
            echo No se puede ejecutar programas DOS en sistemas de 64 bits.
        )
    )
    pause
```

Comment: Y ¿Cuál es tu pregunta?

Comment: Gracias, ya me la respondieron.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema principal de este código es que el script no espera la entrada del usuario antes de verificar la variable de respuesta. Para solucionar este problema, puede utilizar el comando de elección en lugar de establecer `/p`. Aquí está el script modificado:

```
   @echo off
    chcp 65001 > NUL
    echo Verificación sencilla iniciada.
    
    where DOSBox >nul 2>&1
    if %errorlevel% equ 0 (
        echo DOSBox está instalado en el sistema.
    ) else (
        choice /c sn /m "DOSBox no está instalado. ¿Desea descargarlo?"
        if errorlevel 2 (
            echo No se puede ejecutar programas DOS en sistemas de 64 bits.
        ) else (
            echo Felicidades, ¡entró al segundo if!
        )
    )
    pause
    exit
```

Este script modificado utiliza el comando de elección para obtener la entrada del usuario. La opción `/c` especifica la lista de caracteres de entrada válidos (en este caso, s y n). La opción `/m` especifica el mensaje que se mostrará al usuario. La variable nivel de error se establecerá en el índice de la tecla que se presionó (siendo la primera opción 1, la segunda opción 2, y así sucesivamente).

En este caso, si el usuario presiona n, la variable nivel de error se establecerá en 2 y la declaración `if` se evaluará como verdadera. Si el usuario presiona s, la variable nivel de error se establecerá en 1 y la declaración `if` se evaluará como falsa.